# ExternalException saving System.Drawing.Bitmap with same name in different folder

Tags: vb.net, debugging, exception, bitmap

I'm working on an automated image cropper, and whenever I save the cropped image as an arbitrary name (example: `C:\test.jpg` -> `C:\blargh.jpg`) it works fine, but when I save it with the same filename in a different folder (example: `C:\test.jpg` -> `C:\tmp\test.jpg`), a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException` is thrown.  MSDN says such an error arises when "The image was saved with the wrong image format --or-- The image was saved to the same file it was created from."

My guess is that VB is trying to be smart by checking the open-filename against the save-filename, but is ignoring the folders.  How can I get around this annoying behavior?  Here's my code at the moment:

```
    Dim CropImage = New Bitmap(CropRect.Width, CropRect.Height)
        'save in "output" folder
        Dim tmp() As String 'directory, filename
        Dim strIsolatedFolder As String
        Dim intUBound As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        'split the sting at all the backslashes
        tmp = Split(filename, "\")
        'find out how many pieces there are
        intUBound = UBound(tmp)
        'I want all but the last piece
        strIsolatedFolder = ""
        For i As Integer = 0 To intUBound - 1
            If i = 0 Then
                strIsolatedFolder = tmp(i)
            Else
                're-add all backslashes except the very last one!
                strIsolatedFolder = strIsolatedFolder & "\" & tmp(i)
            End If
        Next i
        ' strIsolatedFolder will be the part before the last '\' (the directory)
        ' tmp.Last will be the part after (the filename, including extension)
        Dim saveAs As String = strIsolatedFolder & "\output\" & System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(tmp.Last, strExtension) 'save in folder "output"
    Using grp = Graphics.FromImage(CropImage)
        grp.DrawImage(bmpSource, New Rectangle(0, 0, CropRect.Width, CropRect.Height), CropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    Select Case strExtension
            Case "jpg"
                CropImage.Save(saveAs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            Case "bmp"
                CropImage.Save(saveAs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
            Case "gif"
                CropImage.Save(saveAs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
        End Select
    End Using
```

Given:

1. `filename` is actually a filename of a VB-loadable image
2. `strExtension` is always "jpg", "bmp", or "gif"
3. `bmpSource` is a private member of type `System.Drawing.Bitmap` that contains a valid image
4. `CropRect` is a `Rectangle` withing the bounds of `bmpSource`
5. The error still occurs when the input and output file extensions are the same
6. There is no logic error in the addition of the folder.  Using breakpoints, I figured out that the final value of `saveAs` was constructed perfectly.  Example: `C:\Users\Snoopy\Documents\test.bmp` would become `C:\Users\Snoopy\Documents\output\test.jpg`, assuming `strExtension` is "jpg"

Is there anything to be fixed in my code, or is this truly a bug in VB?

Answer (score 1):

> The image was saved to the same file it was created from

Yes, that's a very common reason to get this exception.  But not the only one.  You'll also get it when there is *any* reason that Image.Save() cannot write the file.  The exception message stinks, you have to find out why.  Common mistakes are not having write access to the directory, saving with a filename that's the same as a subdirectory, saving to a directory that doesn't exists.  And a scenario like this:

- you started writing your code, the save worked fine
- you started an image viewer to look how it turned out
- that image viewer put a *lock* on the file
- you made a few corrections to your code and reran the program, using the same filename
- kaboom.  The image viewer still has the file locked.  You have to close the viewer.

If you absolutely have no idea then you can get an error code from SysInternals' Process Monitor.  You'll see your program trying to open the file and failing at it.

Also note the mistake in your Save() call, you always save the image in the PNG format since you didn't use the overload with the ImageFormat argument.  So your .jpg file actually contains a png.

Comment: Fixed the call to `Save`, but the file is not locked, and the HRESULT of the error is a generic E_FAIL (unspecified error).  The read was successful.  The write was not.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  Apparently, `Bitmap.Save` *does not* create a folder if I tell it to save in a nonexistent folder, as I had assumed.  Once I added

```
If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(strIsolatedDirectory & "\output")) Then System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(strIsolatedDirectory & "\output")
```

before the call to `Save`, the code worked.